# replace multiple substrings in a string , Array vs HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

There are 2 functions defined below. They does the exactly same function i.e takes input a template (in which one wants to replace some substrings) and array of strings values( key value pair to replace, ex:[subStrToReplace1,value1,subStrToReplace1,value2,.....]) and returns the replaced String.

In second function I am iterating over words of the templates and searching for the relevant key if exist in hashmap and then next word. If I want to replace a word with some substring , which I again want to replace with some other key in values, I need to iterate over template twice. Thats what I did.

I would like to know which one should I use and why ? Any than alternative better than these are also welcome.

1st function

```
public static String populateTemplate1(String template, String... values) {
    String populatedTemplate = template;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
        populatedTemplate = populatedTemplate.replace(values[i], values[i + 1]);
    }
    return populatedTemplate;
}
```

2nd function

```
public static String populateTemplate2(String template, String... values) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
        map.put(values[i],values[i+1]);
    }
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String word : map.keySet()) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            regex.append('|');
        }
        regex.append(Pattern.quote(word));
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toString());

    int N0OfIterationOverTemplate =2;
    // Pattern allowing to extract only the words
    // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    StringBuilder populatedTemplate=new StringBuilder();;

    String temp_template=template;

    while(N0OfIterationOverTemplate!=0){
        populatedTemplate = new StringBuilder();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp_template);
        int fromIndex = 0;
        while (matcher.find(fromIndex)) {
            // The start index of the current word
            int startIdx = matcher.start();
            if (fromIndex < startIdx) {
                // Add what we have between two words
                populatedTemplate.append(temp_template, fromIndex, startIdx);
            }
            // The current word
            String word = matcher.group();
            // Replace the word by itself or what we have in the map
            // populatedTemplate.append(map.getOrDefault(word, word));

            if (map.get(word) == null) {
                populatedTemplate.append(word);
            }
            else {
                populatedTemplate.append(map.get(word));
            }

            // Start the next find from the end index of the current word
            fromIndex = matcher.end();
        }
        if (fromIndex < temp_template.length()) {
            // Add the remaining sub String
            populatedTemplate.append(temp_template, fromIndex, temp_template.length());
        }

        N0OfIterationOverTemplate--;
        temp_template=populatedTemplate.toString();
    }
    return populatedTemplate.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitively the first one for at least two reasons:

1. It is easier to read and shorter, so it is easier to maintain as it is much less error prone
2. You don't rely on a regular expression so it is faster by far

Answer (score 0):

The first function is much clearer and easier to understand. I would prefer it unless you find out (by a profiler) that it takes a considerable amount of time and slows your application down. Then you can figure out how to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Why make things complicated when you can make simple.

Keep in mind that simple solutions tend to be the best.

FYI, if the numbers of elements is and odd number you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I propose this improvement:

```
public static String populateTemplate(String template, String... values) {
        String populatedTemplate = template;
        int nextTarget = 2;
        int lastTarget = values.length - nextTarget;

        for (int i = 0; i <= lastTarget; i += nextTarget) {
            String target = values[i];
            String replacement = values[i + 1];
            populatedTemplate = populatedTemplate.replace(target, replacement);
        }
        return populatedTemplate;
    }
```

"Good programmers write code that humans can understand". Martin Fowler